# ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde)

Tags: python, theano, theano-cuda

This is an error message I get when I execute `import theano`:

> ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde)

I'm using Python 3.5.2 on Windows 10.

I have also asked this of the authors of Theano on GitHub. I'm asking here hoping somebody will be able to help me even if he/she doesn't know Theano's internals. I suspect this has more to do with Python 2 versus 3.

Here's the full error:

```
ERROR (theano.gpuarray): Could not initialize pygpu, support disabled
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 164, in <module>
    use(config.device)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 151, in use
    init_dev(device)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gpuarray\__init__.py", line 66, in init_dev
    avail = dnn.dnn_available(name)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gpuarray\dnn.py", line 174, in dnn_available
    if not dnn_present():
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gpuarray\dnn.py", line 157, in dnn_present
    dnn_present.avail, dnn_present.msg = _dnn_check_version()
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gpuarray\dnn.py", line 130, in _dnn_check_version
    v = version()
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gpuarray\dnn.py", line 316, in version
    profile=False)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\compile\function.py", line 326, in function
    output_keys=output_keys)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\compile\pfunc.py", line 486, in pfunc
    output_keys=output_keys)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1795, in orig_function
    defaults)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 1661, in create
    input_storage=input_storage_lists, storage_map=storage_map)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\link.py", line 699, in make_thunk
    storage_map=storage_map)[:3]
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\vm.py", line 1063, in make_all
    impl=impl))
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\op.py", line 924, in make_thunk
    no_recycling)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\op.py", line 828, in make_c_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1190, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1131, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1589, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, lnk=self, keep_lock=keep_lock)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1155, in module_from_key
    module = lnk.compile_cmodule(location)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cc.py", line 1492, in compile_cmodule
    preargs=preargs)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2318, in compile_str
    return dlimport(lib_filename)
File "C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 302, in dlimport
    rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde)
```

As far as I can tell, Theano compiles a cpp file. Here are the files after the compilation:

```
Directory of [..]\tmp04_uyjkc

04/02/2017  16:41    <DIR>          .
04/02/2017  16:41    <DIR>          ..
04/02/2017  16:08                 0 delete.me
04/02/2017  16:08           108.834 m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde.pyd
04/02/2017  16:08             5.502 mod.cpp
04/02/2017  16:41                 0 ok.txt
04/02/2017  16:08                 0 __init__.py
04/02/2017  16:08    <DIR>          __pycache__
            5 File(s)        114.336 bytes

Directory of [..]\tmp04_uyjkc\__pycache__

04/02/2017  16:08    <DIR>          .
04/02/2017  16:08    <DIR>          ..
04/02/2017  16:08               239 __init__.cpython-35.pyc
            1 File(s)            239 bytes
```

Here's the content of mod.cpp:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "theano_mod_helper.h"
#include "cudnn.h"
//////////////////////
////  Support Code
//////////////////////

#if PY_MAJOR_VERSION >= 3
#define PyInt_FromLong PyLong_FromLong
#endif


    namespace {
    struct __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde {
        PyObject* __ERROR;

        PyObject* storage_V1;


        __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde() {
            // This is only somewhat safe because we:
            //  1) Are not a virtual class
            //  2) Do not use any virtual classes in the members
            //  3) Deal with mostly POD and pointers

            // If this changes, we would have to revise this, but for
            // now I am tired of chasing segfaults because
            // initialization code had an error and some pointer has
            // a junk value.
            memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
        }
        ~__struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde(void) {
            cleanup();
        }

        int init(PyObject* __ERROR, PyObject* storage_V1) {
            Py_XINCREF(storage_V1);
            this->storage_V1 = storage_V1;



            this->__ERROR = __ERROR;
            return 0;
        }
        void cleanup(void) {
            __label_1:

double __DUMMY_1;
__label_4:

double __DUMMY_4;

            Py_XDECREF(this->storage_V1);
        }
        int run(void) {
            int __failure = 0;

    PyObject* py_V1;

        PyObject* V1;

{

    py_V1 = Py_None;
    {Py_XINCREF(py_V1);}

        V1 = NULL;

{
// Op class DnnVersion

        V1 = PyTuple_Pack(2, PyInt_FromLong(CUDNN_VERSION), PyInt_FromLong(cudnnGetVersion()));
        __label_3:

double __DUMMY_3;

}
__label_2:

    if (!__failure) {

        assert(py_V1->ob_refcnt > 1);
        Py_DECREF(py_V1);
        py_V1 = V1 ? V1 : Py_None;
        Py_INCREF(py_V1);

      PyObject* old = PyList_GET_ITEM(storage_V1, 0);
      {Py_XINCREF(py_V1);}
      PyList_SET_ITEM(storage_V1, 0, py_V1);
      {Py_XDECREF(old);}
    }

        Py_XDECREF(V1);

    {Py_XDECREF(py_V1);}

double __DUMMY_2;

}


        if (__failure) {
            // When there is a failure, this code puts the exception
            // in __ERROR.
            PyObject* err_type = NULL;
            PyObject* err_msg = NULL;
            PyObject* err_traceback = NULL;
            PyErr_Fetch(&err_type, &err_msg, &err_traceback);
            if (!err_type) {err_type = Py_None;Py_INCREF(Py_None);}
            if (!err_msg) {err_msg = Py_None; Py_INCREF(Py_None);}
            if (!err_traceback) {err_traceback = Py_None; Py_INCREF(Py_None);}
            PyObject* old_err_type = PyList_GET_ITEM(__ERROR, 0);
            PyObject* old_err_msg = PyList_GET_ITEM(__ERROR, 1);
            PyObject* old_err_traceback = PyList_GET_ITEM(__ERROR, 2);
            PyList_SET_ITEM(__ERROR, 0, err_type);
            PyList_SET_ITEM(__ERROR, 1, err_msg);
            PyList_SET_ITEM(__ERROR, 2, err_traceback);
            {Py_XDECREF(old_err_type);}
            {Py_XDECREF(old_err_msg);}
            {Py_XDECREF(old_err_traceback);}
        }
        // The failure code is returned to index what code block failed.
        return __failure;

        }
    };
    }


        static int __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde_executor(__struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde *self) {
            return self->run();
        }

        static void __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde_destructor(PyObject *capsule) {
            __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde *self = (__struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde *)PyCapsule_GetContext(capsule);
            delete self;
        }

//////////////////////
////  Functions
//////////////////////
static PyObject * instantiate(PyObject * self, PyObject *argtuple) {
  assert(PyTuple_Check(argtuple));
  if (2 != PyTuple_Size(argtuple)){ 
     PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError, "Wrong number of arguments, expected 2, got %i", (int)PyTuple_Size(argtuple));
     return NULL;
  }
  __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde* struct_ptr = new __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde();
  if (struct_ptr->init( PyTuple_GET_ITEM(argtuple, 0),PyTuple_GET_ITEM(argtuple, 1) ) != 0) {
    delete struct_ptr;
    return NULL;
  }
    PyObject* thunk = PyCapsule_New((void*)(&__struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde_executor), NULL, __struct_compiled_op_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde_destructor);
    if (thunk != NULL && PyCapsule_SetContext(thunk, struct_ptr) != 0) {
        PyErr_Clear();
        Py_DECREF(thunk);
        thunk = NULL;
    }

  return thunk; }

//////////////////////
////  Module init
//////////////////////
static PyMethodDef MyMethods[] = {
    {"instantiate", instantiate, METH_VARARGS, "undocumented"} ,
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};
static struct PyModuleDef moduledef = {
      PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
      "m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde",
      NULL,
      -1,
      MyMethods,
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde(void) {
    PyObject *m = PyModule_Create(&moduledef);
    return m;
}
```

Function `PyInit_m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde` seems to be present, so what's the problem?

## edit 1

I copied the files to d:\test and managed to recompile the .pyd file using the same exact command used by Theano (thanks to procmon):

```
import os

add_dir = r'C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin'
os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + add_dir

cmd = r'""C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\g++.exe"  -shared -g -O3 -fno-math-errno -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -Wl,-rpath, -march=haswell -mmmx -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mmovbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul -mpopcnt -mabm -mno-lwp -mfma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mbmi -mbmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mavx2 -msse4.2 -msse4.1 -mlzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1 -mno-clflushopt -mno-xsavec -mno-xsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512ifma -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit -mno-mwaitx --param l1-cache-size=32 --param l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=8192 -mtune=haswell -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64 -I"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" -I"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\include" -I"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof" -L"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\libs" -L"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3" -o d:\test\m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde.pyd d:\test\mod.cpp -lcudnn -lpython35"'
os.system(cmd)
```

I read that pyd files are just DLLs (at least on Windows). The odd thing is that the compiled pyd file doesn't seem to export any function. Maybe I don't understand how Python finds exported functions:

```
D:\test>dumpbin /EXPORTS m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde.pyd
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 12.00.40629.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde.pyd

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde.pyd

    00000000 characteristics
    5896198F time date stamp Sat Feb 04 19:12:31 2017
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           0 number of functions
           0 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name


  Summary

        1000 .CRT
        1000 .bss
        1000 .data
        2000 .debug_abbrev
        1000 .debug_aranges
        1000 .debug_frame
        9000 .debug_info
        2000 .debug_line
        3000 .debug_loc
        1000 .debug_ranges
        1000 .debug_str
        1000 .edata
        1000 .idata
        1000 .pdata
        1000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        2000 .text
        1000 .tls
        1000 .xdata
```

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved this puzzle!

Let's have a look at the g++ command again:

```
"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin\g++.exe"  -shared -g -O3 -fno-math-errno
 -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-write-strings -Wl,-rpath, -march=haswell -mmmx
 -mno-3dnow -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -mno-sse4a -mcx16 -msahf -mmovbe -maes -mno-sha -mpclmul
 -mpopcnt -mabm -mno-lwp -mfma -mno-fma4 -mno-xop -mbmi -mbmi2 -mno-tbm -mavx -mavx2 -msse4.2
 -msse4.1 -mlzcnt -mno-rtm -mno-hle -mrdrnd -mf16c -mfsgsbase -mno-rdseed -mno-prfchw -mno-adx
 -mfxsr -mxsave -mxsaveopt -mno-avx512f -mno-avx512er -mno-avx512cd -mno-avx512pf -mno-prefetchwt1
 -mno-clflushopt -mno-xsavec -mno-xsaves -mno-avx512dq -mno-avx512bw -mno-avx512vl -mno-avx512ifma
 -mno-avx512vbmi -mno-clwb -mno-pcommit -mno-mwaitx --param l1-cache-size=32 --param
 l1-cache-line-size=64 --param l2-cache-size=8192 -mtune=haswell
 -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -m64 -DMS_WIN64
 -I"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include"
 -I"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\include"
 -I"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof"
 -L"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3\libs" -L"C:\Users\Kiuhnm\Anaconda3" -o
 d:\test\m3d1cf20adb1014f04986e6a344a55bde.pyd d:\test\mod.cpp -lcudnn -lpython35
```

Do you see that `-Wl,-rpath,` on the second row? Well, it turns out that, at least in Windows, that swallows up everything which follows it!

`-Wl,a,b,c,d` is used to pass "a b c d" to the linker, but that trailing comma followed by a space is problematic in Windows. Maybe it has to do with the fact that Windows allow spaces in filenames.

After removing the offending part, the output file becomes 40 KB bigger suggesting that it now includes the object code for mod.cpp. Importing the module succeeds, finally, but now I'll have to delve into Theano code to see what's wrong, since the command is dynamically generated.

## EDIT: It wasn't difficult. All one has to do is add

```
[dnn]
library_path=d:\whatever
```

to `.theanorc`. I use a dummy directory because cuDNN's files are already reachable on my system (I must have updated `PATH`).

If you don't have cuDNN installed, then you should never experience this issue.

Now `-Wl,-rpath,` should be `-Wl,-rpath,d:\whatever`, but I didn't check.

Just for completeness, the relevant code is in `[...]Lib\site-packages\Theano\theano\gpuarray\dnn.py` at line 267:

```
def c_compile_args(self):
    return ['-Wl,-rpath,' + config.dnn.library_path]
```

`config.dnn.library_path` is now "d:\whatever" and all is good.